# Undefined: App with mux

Tags: go, mux

So I just started learning Go yesterday and I have been following a fairly simple tutorial on creating a restful api. I can run the tests and everything but when I try to run the app and have it listen on a part it gives me `undefined: App`.

I cannot seem to find the error in this as Initialize and run should be sufficient enough to start the server. The tutorial also has it exactly like this and I followed it carefully.

### UPDATE:

As clarification I attempt to run the program with `go run main.go` and that's what prompts the error.

I also attempted to follow the advice of an answer and ran `go run main.go app.go` and I get `undefined: getUsers` and it points to the line where it says `users, err := getUsers(a.DB, start, count)`. I have added them to my app.go code below.

### main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    a := App{}

    a.Initialize("root", "password", "user")

    a.Run(":8080")
}
```

### app.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB     *sql.DB
}

func (a *App) Initialize(user, password, dbname string) {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@/%s", user, password, dbname)

    var err error

    a.DB, err = sql.Open("mysql", connectionString)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    a.Router = mux.NewRouter()
    a.initializeRoutes()
}

func (a *App) initializeRoutes() {
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/users", a.getUsers).Methods("GET")
}

func (a *App) Run(addr string) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(addr, a.Router))
}

func (a *App) getUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    count, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("count"))
    start, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("start"))

    if count > 10 || count < 1 {
        count = 10
    }

    if start < 0 {
        start = 0
    }

    users, err := getUsers(a.DB, start, count)

    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())

        return
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, users);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you run it? If with `go run` try to pass it all the files:

```
go run main.go app.go
```

Or even with asterisk to catch them all:

```
go run *.go
```

Another option: build application then run it:

```
go build -o app && ./app
```

Comment: Yes sorry I'll edit my post to provide that information I do indeed run it with that command. I tried your solution and ran into some other problems I will update my question.

Comment: Do you mean `getUsers` method of an `App` struct? If yes try call it as `a.getUsers` inside other methods. Or there is another go file(s) where it is defined? If so as them to `go run` too. Even with `*`.

Comment: `getUsers` is defined in my app.go file so it should run with that. I tried using `go run *.go` and it gave me an error of `*.go: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Sorry for the lack of knowledge on the topic. I come from a javascript background and I've been trying to read all of the guides I can on this but documentation becomes a blur after a while.

Comment: Don’t worry. We are have started sometime ago :).  Is it the whole file? I see only a method defined on structure but I do not see a standalone function with such parameters.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I'm getting a grip on structs. I have probably 4 more similar functions like that one (get, post, put ,delete) style and they all pretty much look the same with the same parameters so I guess all of the methods are on the struct. I can put them all in the question but I felt it would just clutter the code since they look idential at definition.

Comment: If they present in the same folder and package just add their files to `go run` and run from that folder. About `*` - looks like shell issues.

Comment: Do I still need to do that if the methods are in the `app.go` file? I figured that they would automatically included when the initialize and run methods were run in the `main.go` file. As for shell issues I don't know if it matter but I am running the commands in the powershell on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Method should be visible to compiler. Now it doesn’t see. Go run is designed to work with individual files. So you can pass all the files explicitly. At a moment do not waste time for a shell issues.

Comment: Not sure about Linux but `go run *.go` will certainly not work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [@Eugene Lisitsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276886/965900).

If `*.go` doesn't work for you for some reason you'll have to manually list all files on which your program depends.

That means that besides `main.go` and `app.go` you also need to list files that define the `getUsers`, `respondWithError` and `respondWithJSON` functions, and if the files in which you define these functions reference some other identifiers that are defined in yet other files you'll also need to include those and so on.

And as you can see this can get pretty annoying pretty quickly so it might be a good idea to put all of your app code, and all other code that's outside of the main.go file into separate packages, then have main.go import those packages, and with that you should be able to run your app with `go run main.go`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Maybe we follow the same [tutorial](https://medium.com/@kelvinpfw/building-and-testing-a-rest-api-in-golang-using-gorilla-mux-and-mysql-1f0518818ff6).
try this:

```
go build .  // create a file end with ".exe", my file name is "golang.exe"
./golang.exe
```

then it's ok!